# SQL: LAG with variable parameter

Tags: sql, variables, impala, lag, lead

I want to use the lag function and make it depend on a variable, but it gives me an error because it must be of type integer.

I tried lag( pivote, pivote ) but I get the following error:
AnalysisException: The offset parameter of LEAD/LAG must be a constant positive integer: lag(pivote, pivote)

Do you have any alternative?

The code is the following:

```
select 
    *
    ,if ( Monto > 0  
     , 0
     , lag( pivote, pivote ) OVER( partition by ID order by Fecha ) 
    ) as B
    
FROM(
    select 
        *, 
    row_number() OVER( partition by ID order by Fecha ) as pivote 
    FROM table1
    ) as base
;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - user mentioned the dbms - its cloudera impala.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably mentioned `pivote` twice in lag(). can you please try below SQL -

```
select 
    base.*
    ,if ( Monto > 0  
     , 0
     , lag( base.pivote ) OVER( partition by ID order by Fecha ) 
    ) as B
    
FROM(
    select 
        t.*, 
    row_number() OVER( partition by ID order by Fecha ) as pivote 
    FROM table1 t
    ) as base
```